# Image Carousel with images from Media Library Kentico 11

Tags: kentico

I want to create a bootstrap image carousel in Kentico 11 while fetching the images from the media library. Is there any step by step guide creating that in a page?

Comment: Check this link https://devnet.kentico.com/questions/how-can-i-display-images-description-other-file-properties-from-media-library-in-static-html-or-cus .  You can create a custom page type with some properties to get images from library and then use repeater control with transformation using bootstrap carousal to get data from page fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow the below steps :-

- Create a custom page type(content only) to have Image URL(media
  selector), AltText, Redirection URL attribute.
- Create a folder for
  carousel.
- Create pages under the folder for each carousel image and
  upload images via media selector & update other attributes.
- Add the repeater transformation on the page for carousel referencing all
  the pages under the carousel folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using portal engine have a look at the documentation for creating a new Web Part. The dynamic component, which in your case would be an image carousel)

https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/developing-web-parts/creating-new-web-parts

Or have a look at default **Image gallery** Web Part, which renders a number of images.

---

Depending on the implementation, but regarding to getting items from the Media library directly using API, try the API examples on:

https://docs.kentico.com/api11/content-management/media-libraries

Where you end up with something like:

```
MediaFileInfo myFile = MediaFileInfoProvider.GetMediaFileInfo(library.LibraryID, "NewFolder/Image.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Media Gallery Web Part (if you are using Portal Engine).
You need to set:

- Media Library from the list of existing media libraries
- Adjust content transformation according to your needs

UPD:
Transformation Example see below:

```
<a rel="lyteshow[4]" 
  href="<%# HTMLHelper.HTMLEncode(MediaLibraryFunctions.GetMediaFileUrl(Eval("FileLibraryID") ,Eval("FilePath"), Eval("FileGUID"), Eval("FileName"), GetDataControlValue<bool>("UseSecureLinks"), false)) %>?ext=<%# Eval("FileExtension", true) %>" 
  title="<%# ResHelper.GetString(Convert.ToString(Eval("FileDescription", true))) %>"><img 
    src="<%# MediaLibraryFunctions.GetMediaFileUrl(Eval("FileGUID"), Eval("FileName")) %>" 
    alt="<%# ResHelper.GetString(Convert.ToString(Eval("FileDescription", true))) %>" 
    title="<%# ResHelper.GetString(Convert.ToString(Eval("FileTitle", true))) %>" 
    width="140" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: I am not able to find such a web part in the list. Have you created a custom one?

Comment: @KunalChawla, it's a standard web-part from Media Library category, I am using K11. You can check the screenshot: https://gyazo.com/a2d09eff8b9827fc4468417e93eaf734